# How to get Content-Type of URL using urllib3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I need to get the content-type of an internet resource not a local file. How can I get the MIME type from a resource behind an URL.

I have tried this :

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request("GET",url)
print(response.headers)
```

How can I get the Content-Type, can be done using urllib3 and how or if not what is the other way?

Comment: you're almost there...
`response.headers['Content-Type']` will do your job.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there:

```
>>> response.headers['Content-Type']
'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

If the header is set correctly, you should be able to parse this to determine the MIME type.